# Submitted POST content overwrite additonal URL params

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I submit data via a xhr request which contains POST data along with some URL params where the POST data is a JSON string.

Here is a sample controller and a sample url

```
public ActionResult Update(string collection)
{
/* method body */
}

somepath/SomeController/Update?_id=r43r34r34r&collection=astring
```

If the POST data now looks like

```
{
    collection: 'SomeString'
}
```

MVC overwrite the param from the URL so that within the controller the collection string has 'SomeString' as value instead of 'astring'. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way around this, beyond using a custom model binder to prioritise the URI, would be to either:

- Change the name of the parameter in the query string and in the action method parameters to something that isn't in the POST request body.
- Pick up directly from the query string in the controller:

  `var aCollection = Request.QueryString["collection"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your method signature to `Update(string[] collection)` you might get (i'm not sure) all the values.